# Transfer int values between class and form

Tags: c#

I'm really confused by now.

I've got a WinForm which holds a large Array

```
int[,] map = new int[1000, 1000];
```

I've also got a class containing a method "Draw".
The draw method now needs to get the value of a position in the array in the form. I tried doing the following thing:

In my Form class, I added

```
public int mapContentAtXY(Point mapPosition)
    {
        return map[mapPosition.X, mapPosition.Y];
    }
```

Now if I try to perform

```
myInt = Ingame.mapContentAtXY(myPoint);
//Note: Ingame is the name of my Form
```

It says

```
Error   2   'Neu.Ingame' does not contain a definition for 'mapAtPositionXY'
```

This is really confusing, I just added that definition, it's also set as public. So why the hell doesn't it work?

Comment: It needs an instance of `InGame` you are trying to call it from a class definition (statically)

Comment: `mapAtPositionXY` or `mapContentAtXY`?

Comment: `Ingame.mapContentAtXY(myPoint)` -> `this.mapContentAtXY(myPoint)`

Answer (score 0):

Your method `mapContentAtXY` is an instance method.

Change `Ingame` to `this`, if you're calling it from within your form instance.

```
myInt = this.mapContentAtXY(myPoint);
```

Otherwise use the form instance

```
myInt = frmInGameInstance.mapContentAtXY(myPoint);
```

Comment: I'm not calling it within my form instance. As I said I'm calling it from the class with the drawing mathod.

Comment: Then use the form instance. If you don't have one, create one:
 `new Ingame().mapContentAtXY(myPoint);`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the instance of the Form to the draw-class by using `this` when you create or call that instance of the draw-class. Then you can access that method through that form instance.

**OR**

Store the `map` not in the form, but in that draw-class. Move the mapContentAtXY method to the draw-class. Use the one instance of the draw-class in your form to update that map.